# How do you evaluate this integral?

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral $\int_{T} (x-y)\text{d}x + (x+y)\text{d}y$ where T is counterclockwise around the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0)$, and $(0,1)$.

I'm completely lost on how to solve this one. And if it does involve finding a parameterization, $r(t)$, could you please explain to me how we found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a line integral over a curve made of three line segments.

There is a standard way to parametrize a line segment from the point ${\bf r_1}=(x_1,y_1)$ to the point ${\bf r_2}=(x_2,y_2)$ which is

$${\bf r}(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = {\bf r_1} + t({\bf r_2}-{\bf r_1}) ~~~~~ 0\leq t\leq1$$

Once you parametrize the curves, you can set up three integrals, each of which will look like $$\int_0^1(x(t)-y(t))x^\prime(t)dt + (x(t)+y(t))y^\prime(t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do any integrals explicitly if you resort to [Greens Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) to evaluate the line integral:

$$\int_T (x-y)dy + (x+y)ydx = \int_{A_T}\frac{\partial (x+y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (x-y)}{\partial y}dxdy = 2\int_{A_T}dxdy = 1$$

since $\int_{A_T}dxdy = \frac{1}{2}$ is the area of the triange.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think this question requires her to actually evaluate the line integrals.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the integration piecewise on the 3 line segments separately, and then sum them together.

The parameterization $r_1(t)$ of the line segment joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is easy.

$$r_1(t) = (t, 0) \quad t \in [0,1]$$

$r_2(t)$ of the line segment joining $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is given by

$$r_2(t) = (1 - t, t) \quad t \in [0,1]$$

$r_3(t)$ of the line segment joining $(0,1)$ and $(0,0)$ is also easy.

$$r_3(t) = (0, 1 - t) \quad t \in [0,1]$$